# code suspends when function placed in SRAM with attribute

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, bare-metal

I am trying to place the function in non-cacheable section away from the RAM, so using **long_call** in the attribute, memory mapping is happening as seen in .map file but code gets stuck when enters the function and suspends.

The function works fine in cacheable memory section which doesn't require **long_call**.

like eg:,

```
#define LOCATE_FUNC  __attribute__((__section__(".mysection"), __long_call__))

void LOCATE_FUNC  add(){...}
```

Any suggestions why this getting stuck?

Comment: What function did you use? Please add it into the post so that the community can see why your issue is happening.

Comment: Why is long_call helping to prevent caching? I thought it was just a feature used for extended addressing modes? If so, then the problem is simply that you are forcing the wrong calling convention. Why can't you just move the function by using `section` only?

Comment: What makes you think that the memory you try to use actually allows execution?

Comment: @Yunnosch Most bare metal ARM don't have much in the way of MMU.

Comment: @Lundin True, but MPUs are a little more available.

Comment: What does "suspend" mean?  I am guessing that it hit a fault handler with a default empty-loop implementation.  Use a debugger and/or implement a more useful exception handler would be my advice.  ARM is a company not a single device or architecture.  What is your target?

Comment: With your debugger, verify that the code has actually been copied to the RAM section on start-up.

Comment: are you switching modes between arm and thumb or thumb to arm?

Comment: baremetal vs operating system doesnt change the mmu options for a processor

Comment: please provide an example, please show the disasembly of the caller and callee for the it works and it doesnt work